# Running unit tests (individually or as large sets) as fast as possible in c++?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I am a C++ newbie, and I'd basically like to know how to set things up to run unit tests as fast as possible, which I think is pretty equivalent in my case to compiling as fast as possible, without regard for anything else. So if there's practices to avoid, frameworks that are faster or slower, or compiler flags I want, what are they?

For a single module with few dependencies, I can imagine a case where loading the app, then on each change to the relevant module reload it in Cling or some other incrementally capable C++ compiler and then run the unit test as code. I've done similar things in Jupyter notebooks during large python projects.

I hope there's a better way than what I've just described.

Comment: Almost all unit testing frameworks have options to execute a subset of tests by using name-based filtering, for example: [in gtest](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#running-a-subset-of-the-tests). That said, when you move to C++, you will lose something - the C++ program cannot retain the execution states (e.g. data in memory) between different runs, unlike Jupyter. Data has to be explicitly saved and loaded. Also, you cannot pause a program (e.g. with breakpoints) and save the state at that point.

Comment: I know and use test filtering, but compilation can still take longer than actually necessary for the test even with a well-formed makefile. Breakpoints with the ability to edit code would be exactly what I need, so is there any option, even if it sacrifices reliability, usability, or speed-of-compiled code?

Comment: Hi ElliotJJ, this site is not made for broad polls, and in the current form, your question looks pretty much like this. Do you have a *real, measurable* performance problem with some tests (or the compilation of the tests) you have *already written*, so you can make your question make more focussed?

Comment: I do have  a concrete purpose: I'd like to set up some kind of simple indicator for whether a unit test or a small set of unit tests are passing, and have it live-update as the code is edited with absolutely minimal latency. A few seconds is better than many seconds, but I'd really like milliseconds if my test is small enough and my code has few enough dependencies.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio has the ability to 'Edit and Continue', i.e. recompile while debugging and resuming execution afterwards. However, I've found it to be so limited that it's practically useless.

Answer (score 2):

As you surmise, the critical point in getting a C++ unit test suite to run quickly is to minimize compilation time. The key to having fast compilation in a C++ project is to ensure that you religiously follow the Interface Segregation Principle. Each different type of client of any major class should have a separate interface into that class, declared in a separate header file. This means that if the class interface had to change because of a different client's requirements, the first class does not need to be recompiled as its interface remains unchanged. This minimizes the portions of the system that need recompilation on each modification.

(People often wonder about the utility of the ISP. I point out that it was created by Robert Martin while he was working as a C++ programmer)

Other steps to reduce compile time should also be used: make sure your compiler and project are both on fast storage, preferably SSDs. And make sure you have plenty of RAM too.

Answer (score 0):

> For a single module with few dependencies, I can imagine a case where loading the app, then on each change to the relevant module reload it in Cling or some other incrementally capable C++ compiler and then run the unit test as code. I've done similar things in Jupyter notebooks during large python projects.

The simplest way of making unit tests run quickly is to write unit tests. What you have just described is not unit testing, but a form of automated application testing.

Use a unit testing framework, and create tests which only exercise the unit of functionality you wish to test. Do not load the the whole application, do not attempt to recompile it on the fly. Instead just write a unit test which tests just the code you are interested in, and does nothing else.

This will also mean you are force to write your application in a very modular fashion, so you can run each unit of functionality independently without starting up the whole app.

Comment: That probably solves things in some cases, but in my aforementioned python case I didn't really have a choice - I was building on top of a heavyweight framework (so incremental compilation should have been viable, but in reality it was quite unpredictable ranging from 30 seconds to several minutes).

Comment: @ElliotJJ if the framework is so badly designed that it forces you to create untestable, non-modular code, then get another framework.

Comment: I could write beautiful tests, it just took a while to compile sometimes.

Comment: @ElliotJJ again, if you have split the code up into small modules then the compilation for the unit tests for that modules is small. e.g. it takes around 20 mins to compile one of our apps, 20 seconds to compile the unit tests for one of the features I added. Better engineering does solve the problem.